# Charge in a capacitor circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electricity, charge, capacitance

[image: The given circuit]

Firstly switch K is being closed and that one capacitor is being fully charged. Then the switch K is being opened again. What will be the difference of total charge in the system before and after closing and reopening the switch?

This question was asked in a public examination and the answer given is 0C (no difference in charge).
But I attempted this question and got an answer of 1/3CV cause at first the resultant capacitance is C then the charge will be CV and after K is being opened the resultant capacitance will becomes 2/3C thus the charge will become 2/3CV. Then the difference will be 1/3CV

Why am I wrong? Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Before you open the switch, the current through the switch will be zero. What changes when you open a switch through which no current is flowing?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that charge is conserved so the total system charge doesn't change between switch events. Therefore, the difference of total system charge before and after switching would be zero.